# Extract data from flat file to a table

Tags: sql, plsql, load, oracle9i

I'm using Oracle database 9i.
I want to extract data from flat file(.txt) then insert them into a table (on the client) using other than sql_loader, utl_file, external table, sqldeveloper, toad.

Example of flat file source :

> Allain Analyst 13456...
>
> King manager 98768  ...

Comment: An example of the flat file would be useful. And do you mean you don't want to use any of those softwares? Is there anything you do have available?

Comment: I edited my post. I want to use other solution than sql_loader, utl_file, external table, sqldeveloper, toad.

Comment: And can you define that other solution for us to guide.

Comment: Any other solution without using Oracle tools nor sql_loader, utl_file, external table.

Comment: Why are you prevented from using all the tools designed to solve this particular problem?  Normally, when someone is trying to solve a problem, identifies the tools that are designed to solve the problem, and then rules those tools out, there is a lot of backstory that would be needed to figure out what a viable approach might look like.  You could, of course, write a Java/ C#/ Python/ Perl/ Whatever script that does what `SQL*Loader` does.  But that's a lot of code to write just to replace a standard tool that Oracle provides for free.

Comment: it's our customer that eliminated these solutions. Note in the existing solution we used the Oracle_loader.

Comment: What denotes the separation of the columns in the data? Is that three columns, space delimited?

Comment: 10 columns without using a separator.
For example, the first column set to 10 characters, 15 characters the 2nd ect.

Comment: So you want to insert data into the database without using any of the known good methods for inserting data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

This extracts data from file_name.csv file and inserts it into EX_TABLE

```
create table EX_TABLE(
                         COL1 varchar2(13 BYTE)
                         ,COL2 varchar2(250 CHAR)
                         ,COL3  varchar2(210 CHAR)
                         ,COL4 varchar2(70 CHAR)
                        )
organization external
(type oracle_loader
default directory EXT_DIR
access parameters
(
  records delimited by newline
  fields terminated by ','
  missing field values are null
  reject rows with all null 
  fields(COL1 CHAR(13)
         ,COL2 char(250)
         ,COL3 char(210)
         ,COL4 char(70)
         )
)

location ('file_name.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited
;
```

Comment: This assumes the fields are comma delimited? Looking at the sample file, there is no delimiter so it must either be positional or something else.

Comment: Yes this one is for .csv files. Below I have answered for simple .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE EX_TABLE
   (    COL1 varchar2(3 BYTE)
                         ,COL2 varchar2(3 CHAR)
                         ,COL3  varchar2(1 CHAR)
                         ,COL4 varchar2(10 CHAR)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY DAT_DIR
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY \n 
      CHARACTERSET JA16SJISTILDE BADFILE BAD_DIR : 'test_%p_%a.bad' LOGFILE LOG_DIR : 'test_%p_%a.log' READSIZE 10485760 FIELDS LRTRIM MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL REJECT ROWS
WITH ALL NULL FIELDS ( COL1 ( 1: 3) CHAR(3) ,COL2 ( 4: 6) CHAR(3) ,COL3 ( 7: 7) CHAR(1) COL4 ( 8: 17) CHAR(10) ))
      LOCATION
       ( 'STS.txt'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Loading data to external table based on position in the file